# Getting duplicate values in sas inspite of using distinct, how can I delete them?

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

[image: OUTPUT OF CODE]PROGRAM(Appending two tables and storing it in the later one) :

```
proc sql;
   create table tdstagng.aa as
   select distinct * from tdstagng.aa
   outer union corr
   select distinct * from WORK.DYNAMIC
   ORDER by Cdate;`
quit;
```

OUTPUT

This image is the output of the code, Cdate is the column that fetches the current date.) The goal of program is to build a historical data to mark changes with time.

In the date 10/15/18 there are duplicate values eventhough the whole row is same (instead of 7 rows for that date there are 14 rows), how do I get rid of this? I have marked with arrows the duplicated rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You selected two distinct sets and then concatenated them instead of just unioning them.  That is what is leading to duplicate rows.

Did you try removing the `outer` keyword?  Here is example using SASHELP.CLASS data.

```
23   proc sql ;
24   create table test1 as
25   select * from sashelp.class where name like 'A%'
26   union corr
27   select * from sashelp.class where sex = 'F'
28   ;
NOTE: Table WORK.TEST1 created, with 10 rows and 5 columns.

29   create table test2 as
30   select * from sashelp.class where name like 'A%'
31   outer union corr
32   select * from sashelp.class where sex = 'F'
33   ;
NOTE: Table WORK.TEST2 created, with 11 rows and 5 columns.
```

Or making a sub-query?

```
45
46   create table test3 as
47   select distinct * from
48   (
49   select * from sashelp.class where name like 'A%'
50   outer union corr
51   select * from sashelp.class where sex = 'F'
52   )
53   ;
NOTE: Table WORK.TEST3 created, with 10 rows and 5 columns.
```

Comment: Outer does the appending, if I remove that it won't append my tables, yes I tried doing distinct overall but it is giving me error

Comment: I don't understand. UNION combines the sets. What is OUTER adding other than keeping the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sql;
   create table tdstagng.aa as
   select distinct * from tdstagng.aa
   union
   select distinct * from WORK.DYNAMIC
   ORDER by Cdate;
quit;
```

Try removing outer and CORR.

Comment: I did that and now I am not getting duplicates. The outer union corr was the code geenrated when I appended two tables via query builder and later checkd the code.

Answer (score 0):

What's date format in  CDate column? 
It could be due to DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM format -- original date value has time hidden in it;

If it is the case, you could define computed column using function `datepart(CDate)` -- it keeps only date out of datetime value